# Deleting lines beginning with a string

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, aws

I wrote a bash script that I use to backup certain directories to the cloud. I then direct that output to a log file.

The log file consists of lines starting with either "upload" or "Completed". I am trying to delete all the lines starting with "Completed" (which only tells me the amount of data uploaded) and keep the lines starting with "upload". This will give me a list of files that I have uploaded. It looks something like this:

```
Completed 26.0 KiB/~26.0 KiB (109.4 KiB/s) 
upload: Documents/Homepage/Home.html 
Completed 26.0 KiB/~26.0 KiB (109.4 KiB/s) 
Completed 26.9 KiB/~26.9 KiB (109 Bytes/s) 
upload: Documents/backup.sh 
Completed 26.9 KiB/~26.9 KiB (109 Bytes/s)
```

I have researched and tried numerous things for hours, but nothing seems to work. For example, I believe that this should do what I want:

```
sed '/^Completed/d' kdoc.log > kdoc.bak
```

but that ends up deleting every line in the file.

If I try `sed '/^Completed*$/d' kdoc.log > kdoc.bak` then nothing is deleted.

I have also tried the reverse: deleting any line that *doesn't* start with upload:

```
sed '/^upload/!d' kdoc.log > kdoc.bak
```

but that also deletes every line in the file.

If I try searching for "Completed" in any part of the string (i.e., `ed '/Completed/d' kdoc.log > kdoc.bak`) it also deletes every line in the file.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Every page that I've visited that described how to do is telling me that these should work, and yet they are not. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Currently running sed 4.8 on Ubuntu 22.04.

**Edit:**

Adding the content of `cat -A kdoc.log` as per @muro:

```
Completed 26.0 KiB/~26.0 KiB (109.4 KiB/s) $
upload: Documents/Homepage/Home.html $
Completed 26.0 KiB/~26.0 KiB (109.4 KiB/s) $
Completed 26.9 KiB/~26.9 KiB (109 Bytes/s) $
upload: Documents/backup.sh $
Completed 26.9 KiB/~26.9 KiB (109 Bytes/s) $
                                                                                     $
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 sync /local s3://remotebucket > kdoc.log 2> kdoc_error.log

sed '/Completed.*$/d' kdoc.log > kdoc.bak
```

Comment: *"It looks something like this"* how are you viewing the file content? is it possible that the viewer is wrapping lines, and the "lines" apparently starting `upload: xxxx` actually belong to the same line as the `Completed` lines?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm viewing them in my text editor, and they are all on separate lines, with separate line numbers.

Comment: @Terrance Yep, I tried that and it just creates a .bak file with all the lines intact. Nothing has changed. It really is a mystery to me why this isn't working.

Comment: @KennethOdle add a representative output of `cat -A kdoc.log` to your post, please

Comment: @Terrance No, I'm not. I was just redirecting to a separate file for testing purposes at this point.

Comment: Well, all my tests on your commands pass.  I am out.  I cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: @Terrance Yeah, I'm thinking that it must be something with the file itself. Your commands do work if I create a fresh log file in my text editor and don't use the one generated by my backup script. I appreciate your taking a look at this one.

Comment: @Terrance I've added a second edit with the script.

Comment: "I wrote a bash script that I use to backup certain directories to the cloud." is the script I am talking about.  Don't post anything that can give away personal info, like change usernames, passwords, IP addresses.  I would be looking more for what that actual script is doing and how it is logging what it is doing.

Comment: I suspect there are control characters in the `aws s3 sync` output that are not being rendered by a simple `cat -A`. Something like `sed /Completed/q' kdoc.log | xxd` or `sed -n '/Completed/{l;q}' kdoc.log` might be more determinative. See also ['cat file' stdout differs from 'cat file > textfile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734050/cat-file-stdout-differs-from-cat-file-textfile) in particular the comments about the aws `--no-progress` and `--color` options.

Comment: Why not simply pipe the file through `grep -v 'Completed'` ? The `-v` inverts the search term, i.e. you get the lines that do _not_ match.

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver was correct: there was something in `aws s3 sync` output. It turns out that the files generated contain a cursor return (`^M`) instead of a newline. Adding this line to the script after the sync command converted the cursor returns to newlines, which `sed` was then able to work with:

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r/ \n/g' kdoc.log
```

I've updated the tags in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: Regarding "instead of a newline" - a newline is a string, usually made up of some combination of a Carriage Return (CR aka `\r`, sometimes displayed as `^M`), and/or a Line Feed (LF, aka `\n`, sometimes displayed as `$`). LF alone is the newline on Unix, CR-LF is the newline on Windows, CR alone and LF-CR are each the newline on other systems (e.g. old Macs apparently). It's a common source of confusion when people use the word newline as it means different things to different people in different contexts. I suspect you meant to say linefeed in this case.

Comment: You don't need to run that sed script, If the records in your file are separated by `\r`s instead of `\n`s then just use awk instead of sed and tell it that: `awk -v RS='\r' '/^upload/' file`, or if you prefer negative logic for some reason, `awk -v RS='\r' '!/^Completed/' file`